# Deleting a block in a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi, have a 3D numpy array described as viz[v][i][k]. Given the example above,

```
    [[[1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]]

 [[1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 1 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]]

 [[1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]]]
```

I would like to delete a certain block for a given v, let's say if v is 0, then i would like to delete the first whole 2d array. How can i do this in python?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
>>> ix = 0
>>> arr
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])

>>> np.delete(arr, ix, axis=0)
array([[[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove a specific 2D matrix from your 3D NumPy matrix as such:

numpy.delete(arr, [index to be deleted], axis to delete array from)

If you wish to delete the first 2D matrix as you wish, you can use:

np.delete(arr=z, obj=[0], axis=0)

as such:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> print(x)
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]]]
>>> np.delete(arr=x, obj=[0], axis=0)
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```